# How to create a grid view page that behaves like the start menu

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps, commandbar

I'm trying to create a grid view page that behaves like the start menu:

If I tap or left click an item in the grid view, I want to navigate to another page.

On the other hand, If I hold or right click an item, I want the item to be selected, I want the command bar displayed and I want to be able to select additional items in the grid view. If only the one item is selected, I want two buttons enabled: Edit and Remove. If two or more items are selected, I only want the Remove button enabled.

I've looked all over and I can't find any information on how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. BTW, I'm using C#. Thanx,

Comment: So, sorry to say but this looks like you're basically looking for someone to produce your code with just 50 S.O. rep points as the incentive. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm not the original question asker, but what I need information on is how to support both selection (with long-press/drag) as well as clicks on items (with a tap) on a grid view. The ItemClick event is only fired if SelectionMode is None.